# What version Ubuntu should I download

Tags: 14.04, 15.10

i will mostly be using ubuntu for afking multiple games, so my question is, should I get 14.04 or 15.10?

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/633077/which-ubuntu-version-should-i-install-14-04-2-lts-or-15-04

Comment: Short answer is 14.04

Comment: 14.04, that's all.

Answer (score -2):

Well, if you are going to be using it for developing or "special" things, go with 14.04. If you want all the new features or speed (particularly for playing games or other) you should get 15.10.

Comment: Why in 15.10 there will be more speed?

Comment: Because they will add more stuff for convenience.